# How do I fix AWS S3 Cors issue?

Tags: amazon-s3

Access to XMLHttpRequest from has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My CORS configuration:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "GET",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "ETag",
        "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
        "x-amz-request-id",
        "x-amz-id-2",
        "Content-Length",
        "Content-Type",
        "Connection",
        "Date",
        "x-amz-version-id",
        "Server"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 10
}
]
```

Request headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,x-amz-content-sha256,x-amz-date,x-amz- 
user-agent
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: just added a couple of Access-Control-Request-Headers that were missing in exposed headers. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

It was trying to reach a wrong region as I didn't specify one

Comment: Can you please add more details for people who might be experiencing the same problem?